# What is the origin of "banana brackets"?

Tags: mathematics, notation, computer-science

["Banana" brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism#Terminology_and_history) are used to denote catamorphisms:

> Another notation found in the literature is [image: (!|f|!)] .

These symbols are very similar to the composition of a $($ and a $|$, is this similarity more than coincidence? I.e. is there some motivation where they represent the same as $|...|$ followed by $(...)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest reference I can find to "banana brackets" is in:

> [image]
>
> - G. Malcolm. [Data structures and program transformation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167642390900237). Science of Computer Programming, 14(2-3):255-280, October 1990.

Where they are clearly crescent-moon/banana shaped symbols: ⦅...⦆.

The later style using $($ and $|$ seems to be a typographic practicality, and is used by Malcolm himself in another publication the same year:

> [image]
>
> - G. Malcolm. [Algebraic data types and program transformation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.221.4281&rep=rep1&type=pdf). PhD thesis, Groningen University, 1990.